# XSRF integration to the application

Tags: gwt, csrf

I was trying to implement XSRF for my application. I followed the guide provided at [gwtproject.org](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html). I even setup a demo and it is working fine. As mentioned in the guide, I wrapped up async call with another async call for getting the XSRF token and everything works fine.

```
XsrfTokenServiceAsync xsrf = (XsrfTokenServiceAsync)GWT.create(XsrfTokenService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)xsrf).setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "xsrf");
xsrf.getNewXsrfToken(new AsyncCallback<XsrfToken>() {

  public void onSuccess(XsrfToken token) {
    MyServiceAsync rpc = (MyServiceAsync)GWT.create(MyService.class);
    ((HasRpcToken) rpc).setRpcToken(token);

    // make XSRF protected RPC call
    rpc.doStuff(new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
      // ...
    });
  }

  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    try {
      throw caught;
    } catch (RpcTokenException e) {
      // Can be thrown for several reasons:
      //   - duplicate session cookie, which may be a sign of a cookie
      //     overwrite attack
      //   - XSRF token cannot be generated because session cookie isn't
      //     present
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      // unexpected
    }
});
```

**My question**: Should I make two async calls for every async call to make is XSRF secure, i.e., One to get the XSRF token and other actual async call? Is their a way to make XSRF token to use it per browser session?. The reason why I asking is this, ours is already a fully coded application, and if former is the case, I have to edit each and every async call and make it XSRF secure and not to mention, performance will be a issue as I have to make 2 async calls everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one Async call - not two. Your client only needs to get a token once, and then you simply tell your service to include this token with each subsequent RPC call.

I actually add this token to the host page using JSP - set it as a JavaScript variable and then access it from my code.

Comment: So you are saying that once I get a xsrf token at the start of the application, I can use the same token for all the future async calls across different modules of the same application?

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep the same session. The server-side code compares a token it gets from the client with a token stored in a session, and raises an exception if they don't match.